# Display a logo regardless if originating from V1 or V2 of API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 versions of an API that provides an array of objects within the response. The object contains a parameter that has a value of "logo_url": "/assets/appicons/garmin-connect.png" (V1) or "logo_url": "//assets.prod.example.com/cmapi/images/sources/garmin.png" (V2).

The code that I am writing must display a logo regardless if the code is coming from V1 or V2 of the 3rd party API.

Here is what I have written so far

```
if(exampleApp.logo_url.includes('fooapi')) {
      return example.logo_url;
    } else {
      return LOGO_BASE_URL + exampleApp.logo_url;
    }
```

How do I support displaying the logo regardless if the application uses V1 or V2?

Comment: Unless `LOGO_BASE_URL` is _external_ - simply remove it? Your first URL is already relative to the domain root with that leading slash, and the second one is protocol-relative, meaning it will be prefixed with either `http:` or `https:`, depending on what the page "embedding" this image is using.

Comment: ```LOGO_BASE_URL``` is valid and must remain to create a valid http request.

Comment: Not sure why that would be that case (you should rather properly _explain_ it, than just _state_ it) - but both of those URLs would go into your else branch here? Well then add another check in there, whether it starts with a `//`, and react accordingly.